Repeated result for if statement in python
token_list = ['lg', 'was', 'beaten']

defined_words = ['hand', 'leg', 'head', 'arm', 'finger', 'wrist', 'thigh']

for i in range(0, len(token_list), 1):
    if token_list[i] in defined_words:
        print(token_list[i])
        break
    elif token_list not in defined_words:
        print('no injury')

In the above code I don't want it to print no injury thrice when all the words in token list is not found in defined list. Let it print no injury once

Then don't print it inside the loop, since that will print it in every loop iteration. Print it once after the loop. Either use a True/False variable to keep track of whether you should print it, or use the for..else construct.

Using sets: S = set(defined_words) ; print(next((t for t in token_list if t in S), 'no injury'))

you've given up way too soon. you're supposed to try harder before asking a question here.

Python has a convenient for-else construct which is useful here:
token_list = ['leg', 'was', 'beaten']

defined_words = ['hand', 'leg', 'head', 'arm', 'finger', 'wrist', 'thigh']

for word in token_list:
    if word in defined_words:
        print(word)
        break
else:
    print('no injury')

Note that the else clause here lines up with the for, not with the if. This else clause will be executed only if the for loop does not break.
Note also that you don’t need range here. Even if you did, you could have simply used range(len(token_list)), omitting the default start and step.

Try this:
token_list = ['lg', 'was', 'beaten']

defined_words = ['hand', 'leg', 'head', 'arm', 'finger', 'wrist', 'thigh']

for word in token_list:
    if word in defined_words:
        print(word)
        break
else:
    print('no injury')

the else clause of the for loop is executed if the end of the loop is reached without breaking early
see: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops
A couple of other things to note...
There's no need to do this:
for i in range(0, len(token_list), 1):
    if token_list[i] in defined_words:

...because Python for loop lets you iterate over the items in a collection directly.
Also elif token_list not in defined_words that you had originally has a problem in that you are testing whether the whole list token_list is one of the elements in defined_words. But this is fixed with the amended code above.
